# Can a generic function's return type be fed into its arguments' types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, recursion, tree, return-type, inference

Let's say I'm building a minimal compiler in TypeScript:

I have parsers that apply to different kinds of files:

```
interface Parser<ParsedTree extends object> {
  parse(buffer: Buffer): ParsedTree;
}
```

I have transforms that may or may not mutate visited nodes of the parsed files' trees:

```
interface Transform<Node, TransformedNode> {
  pre(node: Node): TransformedNode;
  post(node: Node): TransformedNode;
}
```

And I have targets, which accept the transformed trees, and do something with them (ostensibly write them to the fs):

```
interface Target<TransformedTree> {
  write(tree: TransformedTree): void;
}
```

The targets' `TransformedTree` type should be drawn from what the transforms return. Aka., we get the union return type of every transforms' `pre` and `post`, and add it onto the parsed tree node types. To achieve this, we get the parser return types, and then use the following utility type to turn each of the tree type's nodes into a union of itself and the return types of all transforms' `pre` and `post` methods:

```
export type ChildrenUnionWith<T, Append> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object
    ? ChildrenUnionWith<T[K], Append> | Append
    : T[K] | Append;
};
```

Meanwhile, we get the first generic argument of `Transform` by using the following utility to get a union of all `ParsedTree`'s nodes:

```
export type NodeOfTree<Tree> = Tree extends object
  ? ({[K in keyof Tree]: NodeOfTree<Tree[K]>}[keyof Tree] | Tree)
  : Tree;
```

I've tried to piece these types together like so:

```
function compile<
  Parsers extends Parser<object>[],
  Transforms extends Transform<NodeOfTree<ParsedTree>, unknown>[],
  Targets extends Target<TransformedTree>[],
  ParsedTree = ReturnType<Parsers[number]["parse"]>,
  TransformedNode = ReturnType<Transforms[number]["pre" | "post"]>,
  TransformedTree = ChildrenUnionWith<ParsedTree, TransformedNode>
>(parsers: Parsers, transforms: Transforms, targets: Targets) {
  // do something
}
```

This works... but in runtime use, a given `Transform` might act on a node that has been previously transformed. Because of this, I'd like to pipe the return types of all transforms back into its first generic argument... I'd like for the node type to be––not only the union of all `ParsedTree` nodes, but also the union of all `Transform` `pre` and `post` return types.

The following is not working as expected:

```
function compile<
  Parsers extends Parser<object>[],
  Transforms extends Transform<NodeOfTree<ParsedTree> | TransformedNode, unknown>[],
  Targets extends Target<TransformedTree>[],
  ParsedTree = ReturnType<Parsers[number]["parse"]>,
  TransformedNode = ReturnType<Transforms[number]["pre" | "post"]>,
  TransformedTree = ChildrenUnionWith<ParsedTree, TransformedNode>
>(parsers: Parsers, transforms: Transforms, targets: Targets) {
  // do something
}
```

When I pass the following params...

```
compile(
  [{parse: (_: Buffer) => ({a: "b", c: "d"})}],
  [
    {
      pre: (node) => {},
      post: (node) => {},
    },
  ],
  [{write: (node) => {}}],
);
```

... not only are there no type errors, but the `node` type in `pre` and `post` is `any` :/

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might enable the typings for which I'm looking?

Thank you!

Comment: So the type of `node` in the `transforms` callbacks is dependent on the type returned from those same callbacks?  I'm not surprised that contextual typing would fail here; I'd say you should manually annotate `node` in that case. If you still want help, I'd suggest paring down your code above into a true [mcve]; for example, I think `function compile<P extends Parser<object>[], T extends Transform<NodeOfTree<ReturnType<P[number]["parse"]>> | ReturnType<T[number]["pre" | "post"]>, unknown>[]>(parsers: P, transforms: T) { }` has the same symptoms, and can likely be reduced further.

Comment: I whittled this as down as far as I could: `function compile<R>(transform: (node: R) => R) { }` and `compile((node) => 1)`. The compiler can't infer `R`. It's trying to both infer `R` from the type of `node` (generic type inference) and to infer the type of `node` from the type of `R` (contextual typing) and it can't do both at the same time. It's conceivable that the compiler could be changed to do this better (e.g., in this case, `number` would be a good candidate for `R`) but there will always be cases where type inference doesn't do what you want, and you need manual annotations. Sorry!

Comment: And here's the GitHub issue that says it's a design limitation: [microsoft/TypeScript#29771](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29771)

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your answer. Your answers are superb! It does seem like a tough job for the compiler.